# hid.find_all_hid_devices() in asyncio coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, pywinusb

In order to access a a USB HID device connected on my computer I use the function `find_all_hid_devices()`from the `pywinusb` package.

Now I would like to access this HID device from an asyncio coroutine. With the following code

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    from pywinusb import hid
    a = hid.find_all_hid_devices()
```

The following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinusb\hid\core.py", line 122, in find_all_hid_devices
    for interface_data in winapi.enum_device_interfaces(h_info, guid):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinusb\hid\winapi.py", line 466, in enum_device_interfaces
    byref(dev_interface_data) ):
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert
```

The same call to `hid.find_all_hid_devices()` however works on its own, in a plain main without asyncio.

Is this due to the fact that I'm trying to access within a coroutine? What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pywinusb` library is synchronous by design, thus you should call it in thread pool.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def f():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    a = yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, hid.find_all_hid_devices)
```

Synchronous call from coroutine is allowed technically but discouraged because it pauses event loop for long time period.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer!
Once I get my HID device, the code I must run on it is also (unfortunately) synchronous (e.g. `device.dosomething1`, `device.dosomething2`). Would you suggest, although discouraged, that I wrap all these instructions in a thread pool also?

Comment: To be clean: passing sync calls into thread pool is totally fine, the pool is intended to this usage.
Pushing sync call into executor converts it into async call from asyncio perspective.
So yes, please stay on this way.